# In Windows 7, can an optical drive be made "Drive A:" ?

Tags: windows-7, optical-drive, drive-letter

Can I change my CD/DVD Rom drive letter to "A" in Windows 7? Will it hurt anything if I do?

Currently it's set to "R".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be done via **Disk Management** (`Start / Run / diskmgmt.msc`).

No, I don't foresee any ill effects, unless you have some very old software that refuses to accept the fact that A: and B: can be anything other than floppy drives.

Comment: Also, changing the drive letter may break some installed programs, games mostly, that expect the optical drive to be the same place the program was installed from.  And that might break some things.  But seems plenty possible otherwise.

Comment: @killermist: Yes, and of course that's true of *any* drive letter change, not just for optical drives. That's precisely why Disk Management pops up [this warning](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TGmIs.png) whenever you attempt a drive letter change.

Comment: Thank you so much--I changed my main SATA CD/DVD RW drive to be Drive A and my virtual CDR drive to Drive B and so far they all work great. I just like the fact that I can now use those two drive letters for something rather than unassigned.unusable--mainly because I have almost all the alphabet used up on hard disks.

Comment: Games and software in general store path information in the Windows registry. If you move the game/application to another drive or path then you can manually edit these locations in the registry. There are also various tools that find wrong paths, e.g. Registry First Aid.

Comment: @mrt: Like you said, in general they do but not always. They could very well store the paths in their own binary format files. Even if they do use the registry, editing manually only makes sense if all relevant instances are found, and that's the difficult part. No program can guarantee a perfect registry search for all broken paths.